# Drupal 7, Looking for a module that can geo-locate a user and feed them specific data?

Tags: 7, blocks, users, location

I'm trying to build a site where I can geo-locate anonymous users when they visit the site and feed them the appropriate data.

Example: I want to display a certain block if the anonymous user's IP is located within 100 miles radius of NYC.

Is there a module that can plug into Rules as a condition and geo-locate anonymous uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart IP module (https://drupal.org/project/smart_ip) will do the job. It will locate the visitor based on his/her IP address. Anything better than that (e.g. street address) requires Device Geolocation, which comes as a submodule of Smart IP.

Comment: just what i needed! thx